# VPN traffic is quicker than across the internet with open ports

Tags: vpn, routing, latency

I have a site to site VPN link and ports open on its public IP for a service. I can connect up to the remote server using the private Ip address of the remote subnet across the VPN and it takes about 150ms. If however I go across the internet and to the public IP address of the remote site (with ports forwarding the service onto the same private IP address as before) it takes 250ms...

This isnt intuitive to me.. I would have thought that they would take approximately the same time since the route would be the same but thought the VPN link would be a bit slower since the router has to "process" the VPN info and decrypt.

Can anyone explain why it takes an extra 100ms if I go across the net?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Something to do with them doing a DNS reverse lookup on connections from the outside? Or even identd, depending on what the service is.